# C - Linux - kernel module - TCP header

Tags: c, tcp, module, kernel, ipv4

I'm trying to create linux kernel module, that will inspect incoming packets. At the moment, I'm in process of extracting TCP header of packet and reading source and destination port -> However I'm getting incorrect values. I have hook function:

```c
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, 
                       const struct net_device *in, 
                       const struct net_device *out, 
                       int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)) 
{
    struct iphdr *ipp = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
    struct tcphdr *hdr;
    /* Using this to filter data from another machine */
    unsigned long ok_ip = 2396891328;

    /* Some problem, empty network packet. Stop it now. */
    if (!skb)
        return NF_ACCEPT;

    /* Just to track only packets coming from 1 IP */
    if (ipp->saddr != ok_ip)
        return NF_ACCEPT;

    /* Incomming packet is TCP */
    if (ipp->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {
        hdr = (struct tcphdr *) skb_transport_header(skb);
        printk(" TCP ports: source: %d, dest: %d .\n", ntohs(hdr->source), 
                                                       ntohs(hdr->dest));
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to telnet port **21**(not listening there I get):

```
[ 4252.961912]  TCP ports: source: 17664, dest: 52 .
[ 4253.453978]  TCP ports: source: 17664, dest: 52 .
[ 4253.953204]  TCP ports: source: 17664, dest: 48 .
```

And when I telnet port **22** - SSH deamon listening there:

```
[ 4299.239940]  TCP ports: source: 17664, dest: 52 .
[ 4299.240527]  TCP ports: source: 17664, dest: 40 .
[ 4299.552566]  TCP ports: source: 17664, dest: 40 .
```

As visible from output I'm getting very weird results, anyone has idea where problem is coming from? when I compile module I have no errors / warnings. Version of kernel(headers): 3.7.10 . Not using SELinux or similar.

Comment: this might have to do with NAT redirection.  Even though your packet is supposed to be leaving on port 21 and 22, the Router converts this to a dynamic port, and then the server is actually getting a request from this port.  On the way back, the server's header shows this, and the router forwards it to you.  I don't think the header is actually changed (or encapsulated) though, since hte router I think goes into the header and changes it.

Comment: You should try and print outgoing packets too.  If they show the right port, then it is the router changing these values for you.

Comment: There is no NAT.

Both machines are on ESX server, no VLANs. Machines are having IPs: 192.168.221.141/24 and 192.168.221.142/24 so I don't see any possibility how packet can be modified by anything. Also there are no iptables rules, all is set to accept.

Comment: You need to define how they are connected to the network.  Are they on a virtual lan (which you said they aren't), or are they connected to your physical network?  If they're on the vlan, i can see there not being a switch/router, but if their entry point is physical, then I 100 percent doubt its not going through a router/switch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem writing a small firewall for a networking class I just found out the problem I was having. I was casting the tcp header wrong. Try casting to tcp then accessing the port.

Here is a code snippet of it working

```
struct iphdr *ip_header;       // ip header struct
struct tcphdr *tcp_header;     // tcp header struct
struct udphdr *udp_header;     // udp header struct
struct sk_buff *sock_buff;

unsigned int sport ,
             dport;


sock_buff = skb;

if (!sock_buff)
    return NF_ACCEPT;

ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(sock_buff);
if (!ip_header)
    return NF_ACCEPT;


//if TCP PACKET
if(ip_header->protocol==IPPROTO_TCP)
{
    //tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)skb_transport_header(sock_buff); //doing the cast this way gave me the same problem

    tcp_header= (struct tcphdr *)((__u32 *)ip_header+ ip_header->ihl); //this fixed the problem

    sport = htons((unsigned short int) tcp_header->source); //sport now has the source port
    dport = htons((unsigned short int) tcp_header->dest);   //dport now has the dest port
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
`tcp_header= (struct tcphdr *)((__u32 *)ip_header+ ip_header->ihl);`
Fixed my problem.

Comment: You can also use these two functions to get the IP header and TCP header `ip_hdr(sock_buff)` and `tcp_hdr(sock_buff)`

Answer (score 6):

To get the IP header or TCP header from a socket buffer (`skb`), just apply the functions `ip_hdr(skb)` and `tcp_hdr(skb)`.